# How do i sort a 2D array or multiple arrays by the length of the array

Tags: python, arrays

Write a Python function: `def compare_lengths(x,y,z)`:

I have to take as arguments three arrays and checks their lengths and returns them as a triple in order of length.

For example, if the function takes [1,2,3], [10,20,30,40] and [65,32,7] as input, it should return either `([1,2,3], [65,32,7], [10,20,30,40])` or `([65,32,7], [1,2,3], [10,20,30,40])`.

```
def compare_lengths(x,y,z):
    length1 = len(x)
    length2 = len(y)
    length3 = len(z)
    tr = x,y,z
    
tests = [([1,2,3],[10,20,30,40],[65,32,3])]
for x,y,z in tests:
    print(compare_lengths(x,y,z))
```

This is how far I've got but I have no idea where to go from here. Sorry I am a beginner at coding.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not code writing service. Please give solutions you have tried, and why they are not functioning the way you would like them too.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin with `key=len`:

```
l = [[1,2,3], [10,20,30,40], [65,32,7]]

out = sorted(l, key=len)
```

output: `[[1, 2, 3], [65, 32, 7], [10, 20, 30, 40]]`

If you want to sort by multiple criteria (example ascending length, decreasing sum), you can combine the criteria with a `lambda` + `tuple`:

```
out = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (len(x), -sum(x)))
```

output: `[[65, 32, 7], [1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 40]]`

###### as a function with 3 parameters:

```
def compare_lengths(x, y, z):
    return sorted([x, y, z], key=len)
```